# How can I format a number into human-readable hours and minutes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to turn numbers (column A: hours in decimal form) into a human readable format with only minutes and hours in 15 minute intervals, ideally showing the words "minute(s)" and "hour(s)" only if the value is greater than 0.

I've tried applying an approach similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727156/how-do-i-format-a-google-sheets-duration-formatted-cell-to-show-days-hours-and), but I'm not starting out with time data (just numbers).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of options here:

- Floored to 15 minutes:

```
=IFERROR(1/INT(A1)^-1&" hour(s) ")
&IFERROR(1/(MOD(INT(4*A1)/4*60,60))^-1&" minute(s)")
```

- Rounded to 15 minutes:

```
=IFERROR(1/INT(ROUND(4*A1)/4)^-1&" hour(s) ")
&IFERROR(1/(MOD(ROUND(4*A1)/4*60,60))^-1&" minute(s)")
```

| Number of hours | Floored to 15-min | Rounded to 15-min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.25 | 15 minute(s) | 15 minute(s) |
| 4.5 | 4 hour(s) 30 minute(s) | 4 hour(s) 30 minute(s) |
| 3 | 3 hour(s) | 3 hour(s) |
| 0.49 | 15 minute(s) | 30 minute(s) |
| 3.14 | 3 hour(s) | 3 hour(s) 15 minute(s) |
| 3.99 | 3 hour(s) 45 minute(s) | 4 hour(s) |

Notes:

- The `IFERROR(1/x^-1)` is to check for a non-zero value. If it's 0, it causes a division by 0 error, which is caught by `IFERROR`, which then outputs a blank value. This is so I don't have to re-use a calculation in an `IF` function.
- Rounding to the nearest "1/x" can be achieved by `ROUND(x*value)/x`. In this case, it's the nearest quarter, so 1/4.

Answer (score 2):

This is an array formula version of Calculuswhiz's ROUND formula, controlling for the "s" or lack thereof. Place it in the first cell of an otherwise empty column (e.g., B1):

`=ArrayFormula({"Human Readable";IFERROR(1/INT(ROUND(4*A2:A)/4)^-1&" hour"&IF(INT(ROUND(4*A2:A)/4)^-1=1,,"s")&" ") &IFERROR(1/(MOD(ROUND(4*A2:A)/4*60,60))^-1&" minutes")})`

This formula will produce the header and all column results.

You can change the header text in the formula as you like.

Comment: Ah, ArrayFormula. Should've thought of that. Good one.

Comment: The poster doesn't specifically ask for one. Just thought it might be the most efficient approach. Nice job on the formula approach itself.